# Check if column has same value in any row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the following case.

```
+-----------+--------+-------------+
| ArticleID | UserID | IsConnected |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
|         1 |     25 | True        |
|         1 |     45 | True        |
|         2 |     55 | False       |
+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

So I need to create a `View` who will return `True` if there is more than 1 record in the table with same `ArticleID`.

To make this easier the table looks the same, but without `IsConnected` column.

Comment: Can you give us expected output, is it just a single row yes/no or do you want per `ArticleID`? And what code do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, may be

```
select 
 article_id, user_id, 
 case 
   when count(1) over (partition by article_id) > 1 then 'true' 
   else 'false' 
 end is_connected
from something
```

Answer (score 0):

As Charlieface mentioned, what you asked for could mean a few different things, so a little clarity would be good please. This will do literally exactly what you asked:

```
SELECT TOP 1 'True' AS SomeColumnName -- Returns a single row with 'True' when there's at least one pair of dupe rows by ArticleID, otherwise nothing is returned
FROM ArticlesTable
GROUP BY ArticleID
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1 -- Filter out all non-dupes
```

This makes it slightly *better* by returning an actual boolean-based field that evaluates to True or False, and always returns a value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS SomeColumnName -- Returns a single row with a boolean-based field with true or false dependent on if any ArticleID has dupes
FROM ArticlesTable
GROUP BY ArticleID
ORDER BY SomeColumnName DESC
```

Finally this will return all the grouped up rows by `ArticleID` with a boolean-based field for each one meaning if that `ArticleID` has dupes:

```
SELECT ArticleID, CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(1) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT) AS SomeColumnName -- Returns a boolean-based field describing if this particular ArticleID has dupes
FROM ArticlesTable
GROUP BY ArticleID
ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
```